# Data not binding in Xamarin forms Listview group

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using List view Grouping in Xamarin forms, but some how data is not binding. I am using Xamarin Forms 3.1 latest version.  My code is :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FacilityList}"
      IsGroupingEnabled="true" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

And my view model is

```
 private ObservableCollection<FacilitiesGroup> facilityList;
    public ObservableCollection<FacilitiesGroup> FacilityList
    {
        get => facilityList;
        set => SetProperty(ref facilityList, value);
    }

    private Facility selectedItem;
    public Facility SelectedItem
    {
        get => selectedItem;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref selectedItem, value);
        }
    }

    public ICommand ItemTappedCommand { get; set; }

    public FacilityViewModel()
    {
        FacilityDataStore facilityDataStore = new FacilityDataStore();
        var items = facilityDataStore.GetList();
        var groupList = new List<FacilitiesGroup>();
        var group = new FacilitiesGroup()
        {
            Facilities = items.Where(x => x.IsSubscribed == true).ToList(),
            Heading = "Subscribed"
        };
        var group2 = new FacilitiesGroup()
        {
            Facilities = items.Where(x => x.IsSubscribed == false).ToList(),
            Heading = "Unsubscribed"
        };
        groupList.Add(group);
        groupList.Add(group2);
        FacilityList = new ObservableCollection<FacilitiesGroup>(groupList);
    }
```

FacilityGroup Class code is :

```
public class FacilitiesGroup
{
    public List<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
}
```

And Facility class is :

```
public class Facility
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubscribed { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

I  am binding data like :

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new FacilityViewModel();
    }
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my code. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Which data is not binding? Heading, ImageName or Name? or all of it? Are you seeing binding errors in the output window? Can you update the viewmodel code, so we can see how properties are defined and if you are implementing an interface.

Comment: Actually, everything is not binding.

Comment: without more information, I can't really help. I need to see code around the code you have posted. You answered the 1st part of my last comment. What about the rest?

Comment: Sorry, for late reply. I have updated code please look at this

Comment: @Neil, Have you looked on my viewmodel?

Comment: I am sorry I haven’t had a chance to look at it. Hopefully this evening I will have some time to sit down and look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response. I found this [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping), it might be helpful

*Disclaimer*: I am not observing ViewModel/Model boundaries very well. I am just trying to figure out what is not working. you need to update the ViewModels/Models per your requirements and design documents.

I don't think group header is what you are looking for. here is a link to the [Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#headers-and-footers) where it talks about header/footer and has an image

Let's start with the listview 1st. Remove the GroupHeaderTemplate and add GroupDisplayBinding attribute the to the listview.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FacilityList}"
      IsGroupingEnabled="true" 
      HasUnevenRows="True"           
      GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Heading}" <---------
      ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">    
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Once you make that change, if you run the app. you should see two items in the list. Subscribed/Unsubscribed. Progress!

Next, we need to change FacilitiesGroup Model. We need to extend ObservableCollection.

```
public class FacilitiesGroup : ObservableCollection<Facility>
{
    public string Heading { get; set; }
}
```

Next, we need to make a change in the FacilityViewModel

```
public FacilityViewModel()
{
    FacilityDataStore facilityDataStore = new FacilityDataStore();
    var items = facilityDataStore.GetList();
    var groupList = new List<FacilitiesGroup>();
    var group = new FacilitiesGroup()
    {
        Heading = "Subscribed"
    };

    foreach( Facility facility in items.Where(x => x.IsSubscribed == true ) )
    {
        group.Add(facility);
    }

    var group2 = new FacilitiesGroup()
    {
        Heading = "Unsubscribed"
    };

    foreach( Facility facility in items.Where(x => x.IsSubscribed == false ) )
    {
        group2.Add(facility);
    }

    groupList.Add(group);
    groupList.Add(group2);
    FacilityList = new ObservableCollection<FacilitiesGroup>(groupList);
}
```

Hope that helps! Goodluck.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your response. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

First, You did not mention which particular data is not binded. Anyways make sure that the list that you are binding should not be empty or null. Just try below code.

```
<ListView x:Name="FacilityListview"
  IsGroupingEnabled="true" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Now assign the FacilityList as itemsSource below in the controller.

```
FacilityListview.ItemsSource = FacilityList;
```

Comment: FYI, everything is not binding. Also list contains two records. I can see two separator but cant see data.

Comment: can u check the error log and tell me what exactly is the issue